# How to reset focus to the ultragrid cell after resizing the form size in C#

Tags: c#, cell, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an ultragrid and I am resizing the form size dynamically according to no. of rows when user applied filter on it.
I want to reset focus on the ultragrid cell after form resize.
I have tried it in ultraGrid1_AfterRowFilterChanged event.

```
UltraGridCell aCell = this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.Cells["CompanyName"];
this.ultraGrid1.ActiveCell = aCell;
this.ultraGrid1.Focus();
this.ultraGrid1.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode, false, false);
```

But it didn't work.

I want any alternate solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

When the rows are filtered out by the grid the active row is not changing. So in if the active row is filtered out I assume your code will not do anything. To select the first not filtered out row you may use code like this in   AfterRowFlterChanged event:

```
var notFilteredOutRow = this.ultraGrid1.Rows.FirstOrDefault(r => !r.IsFilteredOut);
if (notFilteredOutRow != null)
{
    this.ultraGrid1.ActiveCell = notFilteredOutRow.Cells[0];
    this.ultraGrid1.Focus();
    this.ultraGrid1.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode, false, false);
}
```